# Unwanted UV Vertices

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv

EDIT: Here is the link to my .blend file~

[image]

I'm new to the blender software specifically. An issue I'm having with Blender that I have never experienced with other software is the inability to remove unwanted vertices from my UV texture map.

Because the texture on my mug model is going to be a flat band of pattern and color, I want to line my vertices up in my uv map so there are no distortions in the pattern. However, whenever I weld two corresponding vertices in my map, this happens:

[image: what]

I noticed there is a sort of stack of faces and vertices in this one little spot. I can't delete it to remove it from my uv, so I tried just grabbing it and moving it off the uv area, but that doesn't help me when it comes to welding and tidying up my map. This little stack is made up of all of the faces I don't want to put my image texture on, so it's causing a bit of a roadblock for me.

I tried searching for a solution but I am not too good at describing this problem in search engines and generic searches didn't seem to hold any answers.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the vertices exist on your mesh they will exist in your UV layout if they were selected when you UV unwrapped. I suppose it would be useful if verts could be deleted from a UV layout, but even without that ability it can be worked around without too much trouble, and you can always re-unwrap. One question: are you sure the UV islands of the mesh you are trying to weld correctly correspond with the faces on your mesh that you think they do?

Comment: Emilie, welcome to the site. It will be helpful to those of us who might want to give advice if you would upload a copy of your ~.blend file to a site like [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), and paste the link into your question. That way, those of us who might wish to help, but do not have enough information from your screen shot to do so, have more resources to help solve your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE Emelie. :)  It would be a lot easier to solve your problem if you could add some screenshots of your model in edit mode or [upload your .blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so we can take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone!  I included the .blend file in the original post as asked. When I unwrapped my mesh I only selected the faces that were inside of my seams (or rather the ones that I wanted to make a UV map of).  That strange stray vertex is made up of all of the other vertices, edges, and faces that were not selected when I made my map.  As Samuel said below, I may just have to fix my seams, but if that's the case I'm not quite sure how to properly do it. I've never dealt with seams before. I thought my UV islands were corresponding correctly, but that vertex may prove otherwise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get even texture pattern I think the seams on the mug indeed should be re-arranged.

That "vertice" in the original UV map actually represents all the inner faces of the mug together with mug's handle. That's why the model should be unwrapped and so the seams can be put in this way:

[image]

In this example the seams are placed on:

1. The outer mesh handle's loopcut; it starts on the bottom of it outside and ends on the bottom inside.
2. The inner mesh handle's loopcut.
3. The loopcut opposite the mug' handle.
4. The very top loopcut of the mesh (inner one, so as not to be seen from the outside).

After some UV map tweaking (scaling loopcuts so the shape to be more quad-like and without distortions) and arranging islands, it can look like this:

[image]

<sub>*Note*: if texture on the bottom of the mesh will be seen somehow, then topology there should be rebuilt.</sub>

Thus the texture on your mug will be placed in this way:

[image]

#### Blend file

Comment: I tried it out and this solved my problem!  Thank you very much for taking the time to help me with this.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: @EmelieK. I'm glad it was useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you haven't specified the seams correctly, there's still a vertex joining your UV islands. Make sure that they are correctly separated and unwrap again. 
Also, if you want a vertex to not show up in the UV layout, unselect it from the 3D view.

Comment: That indeed was the problem!  Thank you for your response!